ETIAS requirement for US citizen traveling to Italy with Italian-citizen spouse
When ETIAS visas begin will a US citizen who is traveling to Italy with an Italian citizen spouse need an ETIAS visa?

ETIAS is a travel authorisation for visa-exempt travellers. It is not a visa.
Persons who require a Schengen visa (or have a national visa), do not require an ETIAS.
Persons who have a residence permit/card, do not require an ETIAS.
All others will be required to have a ETIAS.
The question here is if the ETIAS fee of €7 must be paid.
When traveling with (or joining) the EU citizen to their home country (i.e. are not exercising the right of free movement), then they are required to pay the fee. Otherwise you do not have to pay the fee.

will a US citizen who is traveling to Italy with my Italian citizen spouse need an ETIAS visa

Yes, an ETIAS will be required and the fee of €7 must be paid.

Sources:

FAQs on ETIAS - European Union - I read that different rules apply to nationals of visa-exempt countries who are family members of EU nationals or of nationals of Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway, or Switzerland – who counts as a family member?

It is expected that the European Travel Information and Authorisation System (ETIAS) will be operational from the first half of 2025.




ETIAS is not a visa. See the answer to your question in the ETIAS FAQ:

Any citizens from a non-EU country who do not currently need a visa to visit an EU member state for a short-term stay require ETIAS for entry. EU nationals and those who have a residence permit, card or document issued by any EU country are exempt.


Wonder why this is being downvoted...
